# Is there a way to "reuse" a PHP DocBlock?

Tags: php, docblocks

I currently have code like this:

```
/**
 * blah blah blah thing1
 *
 * @return string a thing1
 */
function thing1() {
    //
}

/**
 * blah blah blah thing2
 *
 * @return string a thing2
 */
function thing2() {
    //
}

//dozens more with the same format
```

Is there a more concise way to do that?

Comment: Copy and paste? Maybe if you could be more specific... but the format is meant to be repetitive and somewhat large so that it's easy to read.

Comment: If it's that the annotations are so similar, maybe your functions are also very similar, and perhaps you could make your code more concise (and thus your annotations as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the docblocks are actually identical, often the case when you're overriding an inherited method but maintaining the same signature, you can use `@see`....

```
abstract class MyBaseModel
    /**
     * @param Boolean $excludeDeleted Should soft-deleted records be excluded
     */
    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        ....
    }
}

class MyExtendedModel extends MyBaseModel
    /**
     * Overload the base newQuery() method so that we can inject any security filters into the query
     *
     * @see MyBaseModel::newQuery
     */
    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

but the sample docblocks for your `thing1()` and `thing2()` aren't identical, so there's no concise (lazy) way of doing so in that case

Answer (score 0):

You can use a @see if it is truly the same.

[Documentation relating to this](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.see.pkg.html)

```
/**
 * blah blah blah thing1
 *
 * @return string a thing1
 */
function thing1() {
    //
}

/**
 * @see thing1
 */
function thing2() {
    //
}
```